# What are the Flood?

Tags: halo

I know that the Flood are like the Precursors but what are they? Are they an animal or a synthetic war machine like the forerunner Promethean's?

Answer (score 6):

### The Flood are (originally artificial but still organic) parasites that genetically alter their hosts via digestion.

The origins of the Flood are discussed in the book *Cryptum* by Greg Bear. The significant text is quoted [at this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/15azcn/the_history_of_the_flood/) - and it's much too large to quote here. TLDR: the Flood were an invention by some ancient alien race which, once exposed to living beings in a high enough number, began a hostile takeover, acting like a plague.

[image: Halo Cryptum cover with floating vertical structures]

<s>The identity of the aliens who created the Flood isn't directly revealed, but the [Primordial](https://www.halopedia.org/Primordial) -- likely the last living Precursor -- was said to have known the Flood's origin and purpose (and those it told the secret to committed suicide), so it's likely that it was some sort of Precursor experiment made for warfare.</s>

It is revealed in *Silentium* that the powder was actually an attempt by the Precursors -- who, losing their war with the Forerunners, decided to turn themselves into the dust -- to hijack other life forms and reconstitute themselves using their bodies. The process failed, however, and instead created the precursors to the Flood.

[image: Halo Primordial, a creature three times bigger than man, with two set of arms, one big and one smaller]

Comment: Parallels can be drawn here between the Flood powder and the black liquid from Prometheus.

Comment: Wait, the precursors and forerunners were two different factions? No wonder I was so confused in Halo 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/profile/Ryan-Lam-1/Halo-video-game-franchise-1/answers) that explains the need for the Halo array (the Flood). The explanation of what exactly the Flood is is dependent on the entire history of the Halo universe, starting from the Precursors and their Mantle of Responsibility.